# Android Java MS SQL Statement using method crashes application

Tags: java, android, sql, jdbc, jtds

This is in Android Studio 2.3.3

I'm making an app that takes fields and inserts the inputs into a database with MS SQL. I will make the fields later, but right now I am testing the jdbc connection. I've imported the `jtds-1.3.1` library already and it seems to be working fine. When I debug I get

```
this = {Class@4018} "classcom.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator.MainActivity"
Exception = {NoSuchMethodException@4402} 
name = "onSave"
parameterTypes = {Class[1]@4404} 
recursivePublicMethods = true
arr$ = {Class[1]@4404} 
len$ = 1
i$ = 1
result = null
```

upon clicking a button that runs the `onSave` method (listed below), the application crashes..

```
public static void onSave(String[] args) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException {
    List<String> Db_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("****;user=*;password=*;database=*");
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    String Sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
}
```

I have done some censoring of private information with `*` since this is a real company database, but the connections should all be correct.

Comment: What does it say when it crashes? what line is the error on?

Comment: For some reason there is nothing in the debugger when it crashes. The app says 'Unfortunately, Application has stopped. The debugger:

`Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
`

Comment: I went and enabled everything for the debugger and got:

`this = {Class@4018} "class com.example.pmatthews.appointmentcreator.MainActivity"
Exception = {NoSuchMethodException@4402} 
name = "onSave"
parameterTypes = {Class[1]@4404} 
recursivePublicMethods = true
arr$ = {Class[1]@4404} 
len$ = 1
i$ = 1
result = null`